# Why wxwidgets draw loosely the circles or rounded polygons?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

For example, if I draw this circle

[image: Circle]

is clearly imprecise and ugly. Is there any way to adjust the *sensitivity* of the draw?

edit:

I can summarize to:

```
self.da = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(-1, 800))
self.da.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.paint)

self._buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(500,500) # creating empty buffer
dc = wx.MemoryDC(self._buffer)  # to handle the buffer
dc.SetBackground( wx.Brush("White") )  # setting background
dc.DrawCircle(50,40,100)  #drawing circle


def paint(self, evt):
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.da, self._buffer) #on paint event draw this
```

Comment: If you could provide some example of the code you used to produce this we might be able to make better suggestions.

Comment: its a simple code....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use wx.GCDC because it support **anti-aliased** drawing

Try this:

```
buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(500,500) # creating empty buffer
dc = wx.MemoryDC(buffer)  # to handle the buffer
dc = wx.GCDC(dc)

dc.SetBackground( wx.Brush("White") )  # setting background
dc.DrawCircle(50,40,100)  #drawing circle
dc.DrawCircle(200,200,100)  #drawing circle
```

[image]